# How to convert hex string to float in Java?

Tags: java, string, floating-point, hex

How to convert hexadecimal string to single precision floating point in Java?

For example, how to implement:

float f = HexStringToFloat("BF800000"); // f should now contain -1.0

I ask this because I have tried:

```
float f = (float)(-1.0);
String s = String.format("%08x", Float.floatToRawIntBits(f));
f = Float.intBitsToFloat(Integer.valueOf(s,16).intValue());
```

But I get the following exception:

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "bf800000"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
public class Test {
  public static void main (String[] args) {

        String myString = "BF800000";
        Long i = Long.parseLong(myString, 16);
        Float f = Float.intBitsToFloat(i.intValue());
        System.out.println(f);
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(Float.floatToIntBits(f)));
  }
}
```

Comment: I get:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "BF800000"

Comment: When testing:

Float.intBitsToFloat(Integer.valueOf("BF800000",16).intValue());

I get the exception:

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "BF800000"

Comment: It's overflowing an int.  Switching it to Long.valueOf(myString, 16) doesn't throw the exception, but results in -1.0 instead of 10.0.  Are you sure 10.0 is the correct result?

Comment: that number is too big maybe? try using Long instead of integer.

Comment: i'm with john here, i'm getting -1.0 not 10.0

Comment: Confirmed the listed answer of 10.0 is not correct.  The sample value is -1.0.  Tested with above code and it works (now that it's Long instead of Integer).

Comment: Also, if my memory is working right, the top bit in an IEEE-754 float is the sign bit so the sample would have to be a negative number.

Comment: Also, 10.0 converts to "41200000"

Comment: Hi, yes, "BF800000" is -1.0, and using Long removes the exception.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the hex value to an int (left as an exercise) and then use `Float.intBitsToFloat(int)`