# How to convert Hex value into float in java?

Tags: java, floating-point, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert hex string to float in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071904/how-to-convert-hex-string-to-float-in-java)

i want to convert hexadecimal value into equivalent float value in java.

```
Ex.What is the output of 000C (hexa value) ?
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Check this : stackoverflow.com/questions/1071904/how-to-convert-hex-string-to-float-in-java

Comment: You need to say what the input value is supposed to be.  Is `000C` an integer?  A bitwise representation of a float?  IEE format?  4 hex digits gives just 2 bytes which is too small for a bitwise representation of an IEE 32-bit float.

Comment: yes it is string object.

Answer (score 0):

Read the hex as an integer and use [`intBitsToFloat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat%28int%29).

Comment: @BabuR - read the answers on the linked question.