# How to convert hex string to a float in Rust?

Tags: rust

What's the most straightforward way to convert a hex string into a float? *(without using 3rd party crates)*.

Does Rust provide some equivalent to Python's `struct.unpack('!f', bytes.fromhex('41973333'))`

---

See this question for [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592158) & [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071904), mentioning for reference.

Comment: Why do you stick without crates?

Comment: Since this can be done in a few lines in other languages, I'd like to know how to do primitive operations without introducing middle-ware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite easy without external crates:

```
fn main() {
    // Hex string to 4-bytes, aka. u32
    let bytes = u32::from_str_radix("41973333", 16).unwrap();

    // Reinterpret 4-bytes as f32:
    let float = unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<u32, f32>(bytes) };

    // Print 18.9
    println!("{}", float);
}
```

[Playground link.](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=276fc42cb7c81031c5241f0b8079eb38&version=undefined)

Answer (score 4):

There's [`f32::from_bits`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.from_bits) which performs the `transmute` in safe code. Note that transmuting is not the same as `struct.unpack`, since `struct.unpack` lets you specify endianness and has a well-defined IEEE representation.

Comment: The endianness issue can easily be dealt with with [`{from,to}_{be,le}`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.from_be). `f32::from_bits` also has the advantage to deal with NaN values correctly.

Comment: @mcarton It's not entirely certain that `from_bits` handles NaN more correctly; it's just more conservative. Whether signalling NaNs can actually cause unsafe behaviour is still under debate.

Comment: @mcarton `from_bits` is now exactly equivalent to a `transmute`. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/46012