# Is there a safer way to use unions to convert between integer and floating-point numbers?

Tags: memory, rust, unions

I´m writing a VM in Rust and I have a C and C++ background. I need union-like functionality because on the VM stack I can either store an `int` or a `float`.

In C I had a union:

```c
union stack_record_t {
    int i;
    float f;
};
```

I can use the record as `int` or as `float` with zero runtime overhead. I have a static bytecode analyzer which will find type errors before the bytecode executes, so I don't have to store a flag alongside the record.

I don´t know if it is a good idea to use unions in Rust because they are unsafe. Is there any safe way to do this in Rust - also with zero cost?
Should I just use the unsafe Rust unions?

Comment: Why not use an `enum` in Rust? `union` in Rust was added mostly for FFI. I would never use a `union` without a fair bit of safe wrapper around it, bringing it to the same level as `enum`.

Comment: But an enum requires additional memory because it is tagged right?

Comment: How do you know whether you have an `int` or `float` in your example union?

Comment: Explain "zero overhead". Given `union stack_record arg;`, you can't use `arg.i` or `arg.f` unless you *know* that `arg` *is* an `int` or a `float`, respectively. So how are you passing that knowledge around? If there's a tag stored alongside `arg` that tells you what type it is, that's basically what an `enum` is; the cost of the `enum` isn't "overhead", it's just the cost you were paying anyway, only wrapped into a nice package. If you have some other way of knowing what type `arg` is, then an unsafe `union` might be the correct way to handle it.

Comment: It depends on which instructions are executed from the bytecode. For example if the next instruction is add it will use i if it is addf (add floats) it will use f.

Comment: How should the VM behave if you use an instruction with the "wrong" value? e.g. you use an addf instruction with a value that was set using `i`. In C++ this is undefined behavior; in C or Rust it is defined to reinterpret the bytes (which still may lead to undefined behavior in certain cases, but not for `i32`->`f32` conversions, which is why that conversion is also possible in safe code using [`f32::from_bits`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.from_bits)).

Comment: I have a static bytecode anaylzer which fill find these kind of errors before the bytecode will execute - is there any big runtime overhead when using f32::from_bits?

Comment: Look at the implementation: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/num/f32.rs.html#496-500. It's a very thin layer over transmute, which is basically memcpy.

Comment: Okay, thanks - so I let´s say I want to store a f32 inside an i32 without cast(as) only the bitpattern like unions - how would I do that. Something like: i: i32::from_bits(val.get_bits()) ??

Comment: f32 also has the reverse method: `to_bits()`, so you'd do: `val.to_bits()`. Also note that what @trentcl said is not completely exact, as to_bits and from_bits convert between f32 and u32 (unsigned).

Comment: Okay thanks I will use that then - but I hope the underlying transmutate wont be too slow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`f32::from_bits`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.from_bits) and [`to_bits`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.to_bits) to safely reinterpret the raw bits of a `u32` as an `f32` and vice versa. This is a "free" conversion – it compiles to no code (with optimizations turned on).¹ To convert between `u32` and `i32` you can use `as` casts, which are likewise free when used to change signedness.

It seems to me that `u32` is the common denominator here, so you might consider making a `struct` that contains a `u32` and exposes methods to get or set the appropriate type:

```
pub struct Record(u32);

impl Record {
    fn get_int(&self) -> i32 {
        self.0 as _
    }

    fn get_float(&self) -> f32 {
        f32::from_bits(self.0)
    }

    fn set_int(&mut self, value: i32) {
        self.0 = value as _;
    }

    fn set_float(&mut self, value: f32) {
        self.0 = value.to_bits();
    }
}
```

[Compare the generated code.](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/DYmkJK)

### See Also

- [Is it possible to write Quake's fast InvSqrt() function in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59081890/is-it-possible-to-write-quakes-fast-invsqrt-function-in-rust)
- [Is transmuting bytes to a float safe or might it produce undefined behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43812361/is-transmuting-bytes-to-a-float-safe-or-might-it-produce-undefined-behavior)
- [Is casting between integers expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44685633/is-casting-between-integers-expensive)

---

¹ These functions use `transmute` internally, which reinterprets the bits just as using a union would. So when they are inlined by the optimizer the generated code is the same.