# Convert float64 to hexadecimal in Rust

Tags: rust, ieee-754

I would like to know how to convert a float64 (or float32) to a corresponding binary/hexadecimal format. It would be great to be able to specify endianness as well (prefer to print it in little-endian format).

Linked post: [How to convert hex string to a float in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704630/how-to-convert-hex-string-to-a-float-in-rust)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`f32::to_be_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.to_be_bytes), [`f32::to_le_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.to_le_bytes), or [`f32::to_ne_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f32.html#method.to_ne_bytes) (depending on the desired endianness) and then format the resulting elements of the array:

```rust
let float: f32 = 123.45;
let bytes = float.to_le_bytes();
let hex = format!("{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}", bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);
assert_eq!(hex, "66E6F642");
```

No need for the unsafe and dangerous `transmute`.

[Rust Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=910bcc7af195d9b580973671ca04ef6b)

Comment: Yeah, this seems better to me. Adding on top of the answer to print the result in decimal format:

`let hexd = format!("{:02} {:02} {:02} {:02}", bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);  
println("{}", hexd);
`

Answer (score 0):

It's just the inverse of the operations from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43705692/364696) to the question you linked:

```
fn main() {
    // Hex string to 4-bytes, aka. u32
    let float: f32 = 18.9;
    
    let bytes = unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<f32, u32>(float) };
    
    let hex = format!("{:x}", bytes);
    
    // Print 41973333
    println!("{}", hex);
}
```

[Rust Playground link](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=8a08c81e74d08d83e5aff31bd94f7867)

Call [`.from_be()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.from_be), [`.from_le()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.from_le) or [`.swap_bytes()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.swap_bytes) on the `u32` value (`bytes`) before formatting to alter the byte order. Change from `f32` and `u32` to `f64` and `u64` for larger data types.

Similarly, the other answer to that question (using `f32.from_bits`) has a direct inverse in `f32.to_bits` (though those functions are still marked as unstable).