# How to convert hex string to a f64 in Rust?

Tags: rust

Based on the following question:

[How to convert hex string to a float in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43704630/how-to-convert-hex-string-to-a-float-in-rust)

I've tried the following code:

```
fn main() {
    // Hex string to 8 bytes, aka. u64
    let bytes = u64::from_str_radix("c51981cb", 16).unwrap();

    // Reinterpret 8 bytes as f64:
    let float = unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<u64, f64>(bytes) };
    println!("float: {}", float);
}
```

This compiles and runs, but according to https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html, the answer should be -2456.11206055, rather than the 0.000.... number I'm getting.

Have I got a problem with BE/LE? Or am I making some other mistake?

Comment: Why not try encoding to hex, and then decoding a known-good value? What you have there looks short for a u64.

Comment: You can avoid the transmute (and unsafe code altogether) with [`f64::from_bits()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.f64.html#method.from_bits).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The calculator you linked is for single precision floating point values, but your code assumed double precision floating points, and indeed converting to `u32` and `f32` the single precision floating point type gives the expected result:

```rust
fn main() {
    // Hex string to 4 bytes, aka. u32
    let bits = u32::from_str_radix("c51981cb", 16).unwrap();
    // Reinterpret 4 bytes as f32:
    let float = f32::from_bits(bits);
    println!("float: {float:.8}"); //float: -2456.11206055
}
```